# iOS: How to retrieve the Core Animation draw rate programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, profiling, core-animation

I'd like to query/measure the Core Animation draw rate on iOS. I am aware I can do so by using XCode's Instruments and the CA profiler, but I specifically want to retrieve the same information *from within* the app to display it in the app itself.

A little more context: This is for an app that has an embedded UIWebView, and we want to measure the total framerate of Core Animation for the app.

Any hints or suggestions appreciated, even if it's not a full solution.

Thanks!
Paul